# Burninate [now] now

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

I just discovered the [now](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/now) tag.  It has 6 followers and <s>89</s> <s>43</s> 0 questions.  Its wiki excerpt says:

> Represents a method or function used to obtain the current system time in most languages.

and its full wiki says:

> Examples include:
>
> Java
>
> System.currentTimeMillis()
>
> Ruby
>
> Time.now
>
> MySQL
>
> select NOW()

Most questions it is on have something to do with the current time.  It really does not add any meaningful information to the post.  I don't even know what it is for on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22462775/program-not-displaying-in-console) question, maybe they wanted help [now](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/now)?

Let's get rid of it. [now](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/now).

Comment: It might be worth noting that there's also an (unrelated) [tag:google-now] tag, which is [sometimes overlooked](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/7562700). I've also noticed that [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/7562715) was using both [tag:now] and [tag:google-now] when only the latter was relevant.

Comment: Agreed; there's no reason for it when the [tag:datetime] tag exists and also functions as the "date and time related issues" tag.

Comment: I think the question you reference in you question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22462775/program-not-displaying-in-console) is using the now tag to say Answer the Question NOW!

Comment: Proposal: Change title to "Burinate [now] now"

Comment: @k_g: At least the closing paragraph is amusingly self-referential.

Comment: @k_g OK, I changed it!

Comment: @NobodyNada thanks! I didn't want to change it myself and I can't make suggested edits anymore, so I figured posting in the comments was the way to go :-)

Comment: @k_g: On meta, there are no edit-suggestions for anyone...

Comment: `currentTimeMillis` does not even have `now` in it.

Comment: We are done, as of [tag:now]!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Nobody is an expert on [now](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/now). Nobody watches all questions specifically about [now](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/now).

Burn it [now](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/now).

Answer (score 6):

At this volume, you could just edit away all occurrences of the tag yourself.

Comment: It will reappear. Maybe not [tag:now] but soon.

Comment: @usr There is reputation limit for creating new tags, and one the tag has been gone for a while it will be treated as "new" again if someone tries to use it. On Stack Overflow proper the rep limit is pretty high these days.

Comment: OK, good. I sometimes wonder what power uses creates such worthless tags. Their names should be on a public board. This burnination process is such a waste of time.

Comment: Are you saying that I should have deleted the tag myself, without posting this request, or that this tag is easy to burninate since it has so few questions?